# All older printers are not working in macOS v11 (Big Sur)

Tags: printing, big-sur, scanning

Equipment: Brother MFC-8890DW and Brother MFC-9320CW

I suspect it will work on: All older printers with Big Sur!

On upgrade to Big Sur, I found that my 8-year old expensive Brother MFC printers would no longer work, and that Apple was recommending that we use AirPrint. I could install the printers using [macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina) (or older) drivers, and my scanners would work, but not the printers! AirPrint would not work either.

I scoured the web for many hours and tried 1) Resetting the printer system - no go.  2) Reinstalling CUPS (with SIP disabled and Gatekeeper disabled - no go because of Apple's read-only /usr filesystem ... not getting into setting up remounting the root (/) filesystem because of FileVault problems.

I noticed that this was a problem that everyone was having regardless of their printer brand - indicating that it was a *system* problem.

Comment: "Everyone was having this problem"? Apart from the HP certificate issue, I've not seen wide-spread reports of printer problems on Big Sur. My 14-year-old HP 5200 works fine, and CUPS is broadly identical to Catalina.

Comment: I have the MFC-9320CW, works fine now. I reset the printer system, then rebooted. For me it didn't show the scanner (Image Capture app). So it *should* work!

Answer (score 34):

What worked: I read the error logs on my printers. They pointed me to permission problems with /usr/libexec/cups. Perms should be 755.

To make this work:

- System Integrity Protection should be disabled.
- You must be a sudoer or have root permissions.

**Instructions**

Open a terminal.

- cd to /usr/libexec
- sudo chmod -R 755 cups

That's it! Printing with older drivers works now! AirPrint works. The scanners work. Apparently Apple screwed up the perms on the cups directory that makes printing work when they created their protected filesystem! Urrgghh! This should work with all older printers regardless of brand.

YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for putting a proper answer in! I know it’s a pain to accept later, but it does really help people out and you can always award the answer to someone else if another better answer arrives later.

Comment: No problem.  Just learning the ropes!

Comment: Can you re-enable System Integrity Protection afterward, or must it remain disabled for your changes to stay intact?

Comment: Good question.  I haven't tried re-enabling yet.

Comment: Just re-enabled SIP (with FileVault working).  All changes remained intact.  The only issue was that I had to re-enable full-disk access for a couple of my programs.

Comment: @wkumito Thanks for your question and answer. This will save at least some hardware from being dumped because of a software issue.

Comment: You are welcome.  Glad to share.

Comment: Great research.  Sadly this is the state of planned obsolecence, and great products are being slowly killed off.  I had the same thing with a brick-outhouse HP Laserjet 4, where there are no windows drivers later than XP.  Works perfectly with linux to this day.   Point is, it could happen on the next or future updates too, so perhaps don't be on the bleeding edge to get the updates.  Let someone else take point and find the traps.

Comment: This shouldn't be the bleeding edge., This is a public release, not a beta. I love Apple, but after using their products for decades, and not finding a better alternative I cut them some slack. Sometimes a release is not quite up to par. This is a pattern for Apple from time to time. As long as they don't do this too frequently.  Given that Big Sur was released concurrently with the M1, I think it is great.  It just needs better QC.  Time for a bug fix release, Tim Cook

Comment: @wkumito FWIW, the permissions on `/usr/libexec/cups` and its contents are exactly the same for me on Big Sur as they are on Mojave -- either 555 or 755 -- and everything works here. Nothing should be writing there generally, and cups runs as root.

Comment: @Criggie You can get the drivers from Microsoft: [HP Laserjet 4 drivers for Windows 10 - possible solution](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-Setup-Software-Drivers/HP-Laserjet-4-drivers-for-Windows-10-possible-solution/td-p/7269713).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Nice find!  thank you!  But then I'd need win10 as well :-P

Comment: Apparently something went wrong with my first install of Big Sur - corrupted install.  I attempted a clean install with a reformat of the hard drive.  This time I reinstalled Catalina, downloaded and got everything working, then upgraded to Big Sur. It seems to be working outstandingly!  In any case, if you have the same problem I did with the printers - you have a temporary fix here.

Comment: You don't need to disable SIP to modify the contents of `/usr/libexec/cups`.  I remain unconvinced by this answer. IF it does work, it's because something incidental is making the fix.

Comment: Can confirm. Disabling SIP, changing permissions and re-enabling SIP works. Seem weird, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

Brother DCP-7065DN and MFC-7860DW printers also have connectivity problems with each Big Sur upgrade.

Typically, after the Macs are shut down and restarted each day, we find no connectivity to our printers.

Our two solutions have been to delete and re-install each printer each morning or, just don't ever turn off the Macs.  Neither solution is ideal.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/311161)